# Conditional sum in r using date from 2 dataset

Tags: r, date, sum, conditional-statements

I am trying to do conditional sum in r.
For example, my data looks like:

data1 contains Date, Investor, and `Buyvol` variables

data2 contains only Date variable

I would like to sum Buyvol variables if `data2$Date` is matched with `data1$Date` AND `data1$investor` is equal to 8000.

```
sum(Jan$Buyvol[format(Jan$Date,"%d") == format(event$Date,"%d") & Jan$Investor == 8000])
```

If doing this code above, it shows wrong value of sum when checking with manual date looks like below.

```
sum(Jan$Buyvol[Jan$Date == "2016-01-04" & Jan$Investor == 8000])
sum(Jan$Buyvol[Jan$Date == "2016-01-06" & Jan$Investor == 8000])
sum(Jan$Buyvol[Jan$Date == "2016-01-04" & Jan$Investor == 8000 | Jan$Date == "2016-01-06" & Jan$Investor == 8000])
```

Can I code for this conditional sum without manually type each date? 
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can add your data easily using the `dput` function and you can format your code section in the editor. That way it makes it easier for us to read your post and provide help.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- merge(x = data1, 
           y = data2, 
           by.x = Date, 
           by.y = Date, 
           all.X = FALSE, 
           all.Y = TRUE)

print(sum(x[x$investor == 8000, 'Buyvol']))
```